# Max file descriptors for elasticsearch process is too low - increase to at least [65536]

Tags: linux, ubuntu, elasticsearch

I have been trying to run elastic search but I keep getting the following error: 
max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65536]

I have already tried changing the limits.conf file as well as using 'ulimit -n 65536, but I keep getting the error regardless.

Would be great if someone could help me out - I have looked at a lot of similar searches but nothing has seemed to work!

Comment: Note if you change limits.conf you need to log off and on before it will take effect.

Comment: Yes, I have logged off but still, the error occurs - also even though I have changed the settings in limits.conf, when I use 'ulimit -n', it goes back to 1024 - do you know why this could be?

Comment: Did you also raise the `fs.file-max` with `sysctl`?  https://gist.github.com/luckydev/b2a6ebe793aeacf50ff15331fb3b519d

Comment: Hi, yes I have just tried that but am still getting the same error - do you know what else this could be?

Comment: How are you starting elastic search?  I've seen where even though a user's ulimit is set higher, you inherit a lower limit due to how you start the job.  And can you add the output of `ulimit -H -a` (shows the hard limits) to your question?